# list indices must be integers or slices, not str python

Tags: python

Tengo este diccionario :

```
andalucia={"almeria": (409.5, 93),
           "cadiz":(63, 57),
           "cordoba": (198, 207),
           "granada": (309, 127.5),
           "huelva":  (3, 139.5),
           "jaen":    (295.5, 192),
           "malaga":  (232.5,  75),
           "sevilla": ( 90, 153)}
```

Y el método para calcular la distancia euclídea:

```
 def distancia_euc2D(c1,c2,coords):
    """ Función que recibe dos ciudades y devuelve la distancia entre ellas,
    calculada mediante distancia euclidea en el plano. El tercer argumento de
    la función contiene las coordenadas de todas las ciudades del problema (en
    foma de lista o de diccionario)"""  
    coord_c1= coords[c1]
    coord_c2= coords[c2]
    return math.hypot(coord_c1[0]-coord_c2[0],coord_c1[1]-coord_c2[1])
```

Pero al hacer esto, concretamente al instanciar Viajante_BL , me sale el error descrito en el título:

```
listaCiudad = []
listaCoordenadas = []
for c,v in andalucia.items():
    listaCiudad.append(c)
    listaCoordenadas.append(v)


distancia = distancia_euc2D(listaCiudad[0],listaCiudad[1],listaCoordenadas)

viajante_andalucia = Viajante_BL(lambda x,y:1,2,listaCiudad,distancia)
```

PD: Tampoco sé si mi función lambda estaría bien escrita , en el constructor la tengo tal que así ( mejor=lambda x,y: x < y)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con el testo integro del error. Pero de primeras lo que entiendo es que estás usando "texto" como indices de lista y eso a python no le gusta.

Answer (score 2):

El problema está aquí:

```
distancia = distancia_euc2D(listaCiudad[0],listaCiudad[1],listaCoordenadas)
```

Cuando llamas a la función `distancia_euc2D` le pasas tres parámetros. Los dos primeros son los nombres de las dos primeras ciudades de la lista pero dentro de la función usas esos dos parámetros como indices del tercer parámetro.

Estas haciendo esto:

```
coord_c1= listaCoordenadas["almeria"]
coord_c2= listaCoordenadas["cadiz"]
```

...y no puedes acceder a un indice de una lista con una cadena, solo con números enteros o la notación de "slicing" como `coords[1:4]`.

Me da que te has confundido con un diccionario, que sí funcionaria puesto que accedes a él por la llave que en este caso es texto, por ejemplo:

```
coord_c1 = andalucia["almeria"]
```

...te devuelve `(409.5, 93)` que es el valor de la llave "almeria". Es confuso cuando la forma de acceder a un diccionario y a una lista es con los mismos brackets [].

Comment: Vale  , ya entiendo lo que dices. Y con respecto a la función lambda que paso en la instanciación estaría bien? Pregunta básica , pero soy principiante en Python!

Comment: No uso lambdas a menudo, pero diría que no está bien. Sin ver el resto del código y sin poner la salida completa del error lo único que entiendo de esa línea es que quieres instancias un objeto `viajante_andalucia` de la clase Viajante_BL al que le has pasado un argumento lambda que acepta dos parámetros (x,y) pero que no hace uso de ellos y que además su función es errónea porque pienso que no debería haber ninguna coma y el intérprete no sabe que hacer con eso. No se muy bien que quieres hacer pero creo que el uso de lambda está sobrecargado y te estás complicando innecesariamente.